# How to replace values in a pandas dataframe based on conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I attempt to apply a different formula to a new column "result" based on the column 'C' containing the condition.
If C is 'add' then I would like to add X and Y. When C is 'mult' the result should be X * Y.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'Y': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['add', 'add', 'mult', 'mult', 'mult']})
df['result'] = df['X'] * df['Y']

df.loc[df.C =='add', 'result'] = df.loc[df['C'] =='add', 'X'] \
                                 + df.loc[df['C'] =='add', 'Y']
df
```

The result I get is:

```
      C  X  Y  result
0   add  0  5       5
1   add  1  6       5
2  mult  2  7      14
3  mult  3  8      24
4  mult  4  9      36
```

What I need is 'result' in row 1 being 7

```
      C  X  Y  result
0   add  0  5       5
1   add  1  6       7
2  mult  2  7      14
3  mult  3  8      24
4  mult  4  9      36
```

Comment: Using your code I have the right result on my machine using pandas **0.24.2**

Comment: Ur code is working fine please cross check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code gives right results, but if you want a direct way

```
df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x :  x['X']+x['Y'] if x['C'] == 'add' else x['X']*x['Y'], axis=1 )
```

output :

```
   X  Y     C  result
0  0  5   add       5
1  1  6   add       7
2  2  7  mult      14
3  3  8  mult      24
4  4  9  mult      36
```

Comment: like every other function it has its downsides and its upsides, if you are talking about performance, you should know that performance depends on  your dataset size. So if you have a small dataset just use it, thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

Your solution working nice, also is posible use this alternative with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = df.C =='add'
df['result'] = np.where(mask, df['X'] + df['Y'], df['X'] * df['Y'])        
print (df)

   X  Y     C  result
0  0  5   add       5
1  1  6   add       7
2  2  7  mult      14
3  3  8  mult      24
4  4  9  mult      36
```

If more conditions is possible use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df.C =='add'
m2 = df.C =='mult'
m3 = df.C =='div'
v1 = df['X'] + df['Y']
v2 = df['X'] * df['Y']
v3 = df['X'] / df['Y']

df['result'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], [v1, v2, v3])        
print (df)

   X  Y     C     result
0  0  5   add   5.000000
1  1  6   add   7.000000
2  2  7  mult  14.000000
3  3  8  mult  24.000000
4  4  9   div   0.444444
```